# Mapbox shows wrong current location in android

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using `Mapbox` `sdk` for android.
I want to get current location,and i am also getting,but the problem is:

I am getting wrong current location,which is near Nigeria.
can anyone help me to get perfect location??

here is my `gradle` file's details:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.app.mapboxdemo"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
        implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
        implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.1.3@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.5.3'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-cluster-utils:0.3.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.13.0'
        implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.13.0') {
            transitive = true
        }
    }
```

and here are the permisssions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
```

and here is my code for getting user location:

```
    package com.app.mapboxdemo;// classes needed to initialize map

    import com.mapbox.api.geocoding.v5.MapboxGeocoding;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;

    // classes needed to add location layer
    import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

    import android.location.Location;

    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerPlugin;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.CameraMode;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.RenderMode;
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineListener;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEnginePriority;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;

    // classes needed to add a marker
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;

    // classes to calculate a route
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;
    import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
    import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;

    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.Callback;
    import retrofit2.Response;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;

    // classes needed to launch navigation UI
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;


    // classes needed to add location layer
    import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

    import android.location.Location;

    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;

    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerPlugin;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.modes.RenderMode;
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineListener;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEnginePriority;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
    import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;


    // classes needed to add a marker
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker;
    import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;


    // classes to calculate a route
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;
    import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
    import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;

    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.Callback;
    import retrofit2.Response;

    import android.util.Log;


    // classes needed to launch navigation UI
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;

    import java.util.List;


    public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener {


        private MapView mapView;


        // variables for adding location layer
        private static MapboxMap map;
        private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
        private LocationLayerPlugin locationPlugin;
        private LocationEngine locationEngine;
        private Location originLocation;


        // variables for adding a marker
        private Marker destinationMarker;
        private LatLng originCoord;
        private LatLng destinationCoord;


        // variables for calculating and drawing a route
        private Point originPosition;
        private Point destinationPosition;
        private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
        private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
        private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;

        EditText edtLatitude, edtLongitude;


        private Button button, buttonGetLocation;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw_navigation);
            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {


                    map = mapboxMap;
                    enableLocationPlugin();


                    originCoord = new LatLng(originLocation.getLatitude(), originLocation.getLongitude());
                    /*mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
                            if (destinationMarker != null) {
                                mapboxMap.removeMarker(destinationMarker);
                            }
                            destinationCoord = point;
                            destinationMarker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(destinationCoord)
                            );

                            destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(destinationCoord.getLongitude(), destinationCoord.getLatitude());
                            originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originCoord.getLongitude(), originCoord.getLatitude());
                            getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);


                            button.setEnabled(true);
                            button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);


                        }

                    });*/


                    button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
                    edtLatitude = findViewById(R.id.edtLatitude);
                    edtLongitude = findViewById(R.id.edtLongitude);

                    buttonGetLocation = findViewById(R.id.buttonGetLocation);
                    buttonGetLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "buttonGetLocation onClick: " );
                            checkLatLong(mapboxMap);
                        }
                    });
                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Point origin = originPosition;
                            Point destination = destinationPosition;

                            boolean simulateRoute = true;
                            NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                                .origin(origin)
                                .destination(destination)
                                .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                                .build();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onClick: Start Button");
                            // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
                            NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(NavigationActivity.this, options);
                        }
                    });


                }
            });


        }


        private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {
            NavigationRoute.builder()
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                        if (response.body() == null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                            return;
                        } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                            return;
                        }

                        currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                        // Draw the route on the map
                        if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                            navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                        } else {
                            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                        }
                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        }


        @SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
        private void enableLocationPlugin() {
            // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
            if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

                initializeLocationEngine();
                locationPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine);
                locationPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
                locationPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
                locationPlugin.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);

            } else {
                permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
                permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
        private void initializeLocationEngine() {
            LocationEngineProvider locationEngineProvider = new LocationEngineProvider(this);
            locationEngineProvider.obtainLocationEngineBy(LocationEngine.Type.ANDROID);
            locationEngine = locationEngineProvider.obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
            locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationEngine.activate();
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();


            Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
    //        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationEngine: Latitude is"+lastLocation.getLatitude()+" Longitude is "+lastLocation.getLongitude() );
            if (lastLocation != null) {
                originLocation = lastLocation;
                setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
            } else {
                locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
            }
        }

        private void setCameraPosition(Location location) {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        @Override
        public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
            if (granted) {
                enableLocationPlugin();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
        public void onConnected() {
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                originLocation = location;
                setCameraPosition(location);
                locationEngine.removeLocationEngineListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if (locationEngine != null) {
                locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
            }
            if (locationPlugin != null) {
                locationPlugin.onStart();
            }
            mapView.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (locationEngine != null) {
                locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
            }
            if (locationPlugin != null) {
                locationPlugin.onStop();
            }
            mapView.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
            if (locationEngine != null) {
                locationEngine.deactivate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mapView.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mapView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }



        public void checkLatLong(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            if ((edtLatitude.getText() == null && edtLatitude.getText().length() == 0) && (edtLongitude.getText() == null && edtLongitude.getText().length() == 0)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Proper Longitude and Latitude.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (destinationMarker != null) {
                    map.removeMarker(destinationMarker);
                }
                destinationCoord = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(edtLatitude.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(edtLongitude.getText().toString()));
                destinationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(destinationCoord)
                );
                Log.e(TAG, "checkLatLong: ");
                destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(destinationCoord.getLongitude(), destinationCoord.getLatitude());
                originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originCoord.getLongitude(), originCoord.getLatitude());
                getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);
                setCameraPosition(originLocation);
                button.setEnabled(true);
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);
            }
        }

    }
```

please help me to get user location.
Help is appreciated,i referred a lot of questions but didnt get any solution.
than also,suggest any help in reffering questions too.

Comment: I can't help you with specifics as I know nothing about Android, however whenever my map mysteriously goes to some point in the ocean off the coast of Nigeria I know that the lat/long coordinate hasn't been correctly initialised and has reverted to (0, 0). i.e. latitude is on the equator and longitude is on the Greenwich line. Usually I find that I am accessing the user location too early, before it has a good fix.

Comment: @Magnas is right. The docs for `LocationManager#getLastKnownLocation`, which I'm assuming is being called indirectly here, say that it may return null. But in my experience it often returns 0,0 instead, so you should check for that. You should also check for null in case they ever fix it.

Comment: I tried as u suggested @KevinKrumwiede, but sorry of no use.

Comment: @Magnas,what was the fix,can u tell me?

Comment: Like I said I don't know anything about Android but in initializeLocationEngine it looks like you activate the locationEngine and then immediately try to extract a location. This is probably too soon. It can take some time to geolocate from the GPS. Is there some callback mechanism that is fired during location.activate() that you can interrogate to know that a real, accurate fix has been achieved?

Comment: wait i will post my entire code and than you can get the idea.@Magnas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by making few changes in methods `initializeLocationEngine()` and `enableLocationPlugin()`

Here are the modified methods for answer:

```
    private void enableLocationPlugin() {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

            initializeLocationEngine();
            locationPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine);
            locationPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(true);
            locationPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
            locationPlugin.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
            getLifecycle().addObserver(locationPlugin);
            Log.e(TAG, "enableLocationPlugin:Permission Granted" );

        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
            Log.e(TAG, "enableLocationPlugin:Permission Not Granted" );

        }
    }



    private void initializeLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        locationEngine.activate();
        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
        } else {
            locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you ever tested this before posting it ? this does not work.

Comment: Yes it does @ralphgabb

Comment: No its not, lastLocation  is always null.